# Meaning of tilde in Linux bash (not home directory)

Tags: linux, bash, home-directory

First off, I know that `~/` is the home directory. CDing to `~` or `~/` takes me to the home directory.

However, `cd ~X` takes me to a special place, where `X` seems to be anything.

In bash, if I hit "`cd ~`" and hit tab, it shows a bunch of possible `~X` options like `~mail` and `~postgres` and `~ssh`.  Going to those folders and doing a `pwd` shows me that these folders are not in the home directory; they're all over the place.

They are not aliases. I've checked. 
They're not `env.` variables, or else they'd require a `$`.

What is setting these links, and where can I find where these are being set?

Comment: ~X simply returns the literal "~X"  but ~ returns $HOME and ~+ returns $PWD  - they are not special other than that they fetch shell variables.  i.e. they do not store the values or execute a command to look them up.  They are already defined.  Have you tried ~- ?  I can't think of a use for it, but again, it returns a shell variable $OLDPWD

Answer (score 91):

It's a Bash feature called "[tilde expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html)". It's a function of the shell, not the OS. You'll get different behavior with csh, for example.

To answer your question about where the information comes from: your home directory comes from the variable `$HOME` (no matter what you store there), while other user's homes are retrieved real-time using [`getpwent()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getpwent.3.html). This function is usually controlled by [NSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_Service_Switch); so by default values are pulled out of `/etc/passwd`, though it can be configured to retrieve the information using any source desired, such as NIS, LDAP or an SQL database.

Tilde expansion is more than home directory lookup. Here's a summary:

```
~              $HOME
~fred          (freds home dir)

~+             $PWD       (your current working directory)
~-             $OLDPWD    (your previous directory)
~1             `dirs +1`
~2             `dirs +2`
~-1            `dirs -1`
```

`dirs` and `~1`, `~-1`, etc., are used in conjunction with `pushd` and `popd`.

**Edited to add:**

As [Sean Bright](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21926) pointed out in a comment, the baseline tilde behavior regarding home directories is codified as standard behavior for [POSIX-compliant](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_01) shells. Additionally, the [wordexp()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wordexp.3.html) C API function is specified to implement this behavior. Though, obviously, use with caution.

Comment: as a note [tag:fish] doesn't support any of them except the plain tilde (~)

Comment: why they came up with `~+`? seems rather useless.

Comment: ~+ is roughly the same as .  However, to use something like ./file it has to go to the file system and figure out where . is located - it takes a few cycles.  Using ~+ saves it the work by simply returning the contents of the shell variable $PWD which is already defined as you traverse the file system.

Comment: The `~` and `~username` forms are [specified by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_01), so it's not specifically a bash thing. It may have been added to POSIX since this answer was written though.

Comment: @SeanBright Fair enough; my point was that it was a shell thing, and different shells do different things. And other non-shell things (like GUIs or other programs) may do nothing at all. POSIX, after all, is just a standard saying "please implement these features in your stuff." But you're right, it's worth pointing out the standards involved.

Comment: You can add `=~`when doing string comparison in a test.

Answer (score 36):

Those are the home directories of the users. Try `cd ~(your username)`, for example.

Comment: They're not symlinks, service accounts don't have home directories under /home

Comment: Best answer in my case. Also, in my particular case, it was the root directory/folder, not the home folder.

Answer (score 19):

Are they the home directories of users in `/etc/passwd`?  Services like postgres, sendmail, apache, etc., create system users that have home directories just like normal users.

Comment: Indeed they are ~username is the home directory of the specified user

Answer (score 15):

Those are users. Check your `/etc/passwd`.

`cd ~username` takes you to that user's home directory.

Comment: FTW.  Upvote.  TNX for clearing that up.  I wonder how many cycles and perhaps even a subshell are involved in that one.  Just imagine if your system has 3K users, like at a small ISP.  Yikes.

Answer (score 10):

On my machine, because of the way I have things set up, doing:

```
cd ~             # /work1/jleffler
cd ~jleffler     # /u/jleffler
```

The first pays attention to the value of environment variable `$HOME`; I deliberately set my `$HOME` to a local file system instead of an NFS-mounted file system.  The second reads from the password file (approximately; NIS complicates things a bit) and finds that the password file says my home directory is `/u/jleffler` and changes to that directory.

The annoying stuff is that most software behaves as above (and the POSIX specification for the shell requires this behaviour).  I use some software (and I don't have much choice about using it) that treats the information from the password file as the current value of $HOME, which is wrong.

Applying this to the question - as others have pointed out, '`cd ~x`' goes to the home directory of user 'x', and more generally, whenever tilde expansion is done, `~x` means the home directory of user 'x' (and it is an error if user 'x' does not exist).

---

It might be worth mentioning that:

```
cd ~-       # Change to previous directory ($OLDPWD)
cd ~+       # Change to current directory ($PWD)
```

I can't immediately find a use for '`~+`', unless you do some weird stuff with moving symlinks in the path leading to the current directory.

You can also do:

```
cd -
```

That means the same as `~-`.

Comment: About `cd ~+`: you could potentially use it to check if a directory you're currently in still exists - even if it is a pretty unorthodox way of doing so.

Answer (score 5):

Tilde expansion in Bash:

http://bash-hackers.org/wiki/doku.php/syntax/expansion/tilde

Comment: New link: https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/tilde

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `autofs` then the expansion might actually be coming from `/etc/auto.home` (or similar for your distro).  For example, my `/etc/auto.master` looks like:

```
/home2 auto.home --timeout 60
```

and `/etc/auto.home` looks like:

```
mgalgs -rw,noquota,intr space:/space/mgalgs
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you're seeing OpenDirectory/ActiveDirectory/LDAP users "automounted" into your home directory.

In *nix, `~` will resolve to your home directory.  Likewise `~X` will resolve to 'user X'.

Similar to automount for directories, OpenDirectory/ActiveDirectory/LDAP is used in larger/corporate environments to automount user directories.  These users may be actual people or they can be machine accounts created to provide various features.

If you type <kbd>~</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> you'll see a list of the users on your machine.