# fs in Node.js Doesn't Understand ~/

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I'm trying to check if a directory exists as part of a command-line app in node.js. However, `fs` doesn't seem to understand `~/`. For example, the following returns false...

```
> fs.existsSync('~/Documents')
false
```

...but this returns true...

```
> fs.existsSync('/Users/gtmtg/Documents')
true
```

...even though they're both the same thing.

Why does this happen, and is there are workaround for this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: [It's a Bash feature called "tilde expansion". It's a function of the shell, not the OS.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1660054/612202)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because `~/` is supported by the command shell, not the file system APIs.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, the user's home path (~) is usually stored in the environment variable HOME. So you can try using something like this:

```
fs.existsSync(`${process.env.HOME}/Documents`);
```

Or, you can create a function to process the tilde character, like this:

```
function parseTildeHome(inputPath) {
  return inputPath.replace('~', process.env.HOME);
}

fs.existsSync(parseTildeHome('~/Documents'));
```