# customizing ZSH tilde expansion

Tags: linux, shell, zsh, zsh-completion

## Context

This concerns ZSH tilde expansion (as in [bash tilde expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html%5Fnode/Tilde-Expansion.html)).

Example: `~http` is expanded to `/srv/http` which is (roughly) the home for user `http` set in `/etc/passwd`.

## What I want to do

I would like to configure ZSH in order to get any filename tilde expansion I wish.

This would be something *like* setting `alias ~foo /foo/bar` in my `.zshrc`.

## What I do not want

I *could* create (as root) the user `foo` and set it’s home to `/foo/bar` but since *any* user should be able to do this, such a solution is not acceptable.

Also, this has nothing to do with the completion of `~` to `$HOME`.

## Misc

This post discuss the nature of *bash* tilde expansion: [Meaning of tilde in Linux bash (not home directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998626/meaning-of-tilde-in-linux-bash-not-home-directory).

Thanks for any answer! ;-)

Comment: This sounds like it might fit better on https://superuser.com/

Comment: You are right. However seeing many zsh/bash questions on stackoverflow lead me to ask it here. Should I transfer it to SU.com?

Comment: You probably cannot do that -except by patching the source code of ̀`zsh`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use either (or both) way:

- `hash -d foo=/foo/bar` ([`hash` builtin command](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-hash))
- `foo=/foo/bar/`

Now, we could use `cd ~foo` to change the current directory to `/foo/bar`, too.

It is known as [“Static named directories”](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Static-named-directories) in zsh.

---

Note: when [`CDABLE_VARS` shell option](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-CDABLE_005fVARS) is active, we could do even `cd foo` rather than `cd ~foo` in the above example if the directory (`/foo/bar` in this example) exists.