# What does ~ stand for in a bash command line?

Tags: bash

I know that ~ usually denotes my home directory. But I just accidentally issued

```
touch ~
```

and got a list of I don't know what:

```
~admin  ~Debian-exim/ ~gnats  ~messagebus/  ~postfix/  ~saned  ~systemd-network/  ~xrdp etc...
```

What is this list? What does ~ stand for in this context?

Comment: I think you meant that you typed `touch ~` and __pressed tab two times__, right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning of tilde in Linux bash (not home directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998626/meaning-of-tilde-in-linux-bash-not-home-directory)

Comment: Did you hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> after entering the `~`?

Comment: yes, that was probably what I did. I wasn't aware of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the man page for bash. There you will find a section called Tilde Expansion:

```
If  a  word begins with an unquoted tilde character (`~'), all of the characters preceding the first unquoted slash (or all characters, if there
       is no unquoted slash) are considered a tilde-prefix.  If none of the characters in the tilde-prefix are quoted, the characters in the tilde-pre‐
       fix  following  the  tilde are treated as a possible login name.
```

So you probably got all your possible login names.