# `os.listdir` throws Error2 for `~`

Tags: python-3.8

**python version**: 3.8
**OS**: Manjaro KDE

When I called `os.listdir('/home/user_name')`, it worked fine.

However, when I called `os.listdir('~')`, it threw `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~'`.

Why `os.listdir` failed to understand `~`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It's a Bash feature called "tilde expansion". It's a function of the shell, not the OS.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1660054/9279181)

Thus, the `os` package of python does not recognize `~`

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like this :

```
p = os.path.expanduser('~')
os.listdir(p)
```

You may refer these links :

[Python's os.makedirs doesn't understand “~” in my path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057045/pythons-os-makedirs-doesnt-understand-in-my-path)

[From documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser)